# Plot spheres on a 3D graph using only matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics

I want to plot a graph of 3D spheres that vary in size according to one data set of the format

```
(name, x-coord, y-coord, sphere_volume)
```

These need to be plotted on the graph based against values of x and y, but a fixed z-value is acceptable; it could be a 2D set of axes, just with 3D spheres varying in size instead of the usual circles you can get with a scatter graph. I also want each of these labelled; either with a name, or with a number than then corresponds to a name in a key.

Which matplotlib module should I use for this? I specifically only want to use matplotlib to output the graphics; though other modules can be used to manipulate the data. I was thinking of adapting the output from this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 15 point radii

plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

so that the circles were instead spheres, but I'm not sure how to go about this; any tips? A nice bonus would be to be able to define the colour of the sphere, but this is less important.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123659/scatter-plot-3d-with-labels-and-spheres)

Comment: I was hoping for actual spheres rather than just a wireframe; they don't look fantastic.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958835/matplotlib-color-gradient-in-patches/10995481) what you're looking for?

Comment: Not quite @ImportanceOfBeingErnest; I was hoping for actual spheres rather than that, in a 3D plot.

Comment: Oh, so you do want a 3D plot. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324258/draw-many-spheres-efficiently) (use the code in the question for matplotlib, the answer shows an alternative not using matplotlib).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest This doesn't address the use of a key though?

Comment: You mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374930/matplotlib-annotating-a-3d-scatter-plot ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Not quite; a key is a separate box off to the side. Each sphere will be labelled with a number, but these each correspond to a name; the key should display that info

Comment: Seems that's a totally [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914413/how-to-generate-a-key-in-matplotlib).

Comment: Because the question was closed - I'd have preferred it to be included with the original