# How to generate a key in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a number of 3D spheres in matplotlib, and each of them will be labelled 1,2,3, and so on. I'm doing this using ax.text(). However, each of those numbers corresponds to a name, and I want the key of this data to be displayed next to the plot after it is generate; how would I go about this?

My code so far is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

u = numpy.linspace(0, 2*numpy.pi, 50)
v = numpy.linspace(0, numpy.pi, 50)
x = numpy.outer(numpy.cos(u), numpy.sin(v))
y = numpy.outer(numpy.sin(u), numpy.sin(v))
z = numpy.outer(numpy.ones(numpy.size(u)), numpy.cos(v))

for k in range(1):
    c = [0,0,0]
    ax.text(c[0],c[1],c[2],"1")
    r = .1
    ax.plot_surface(
        r*x + c[0], r*y + c[1], r*z + c[2],
        color='#1f77b4',
        alpha=0.5,
        linewidth=0
        )

plt.show()
```

I want the label "1" to correspond to "Name"; these will both be from lists, but this is just an example!

Comment: See if this helps, "https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/text3d_demo.html"

Comment: @ArtBajji Not really - I want a separate key off to the side, much like a legend.