# Drawing spheres in Mayavi giving empty plot

Tags: python, mayavi

I'm trying to visualize 10000 spheres, each with center position and radius data.

I did come across this helpful link and followed it throught: [draw many spheres efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324258/draw-many-spheres-efficiently)

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import cos,sin,cross,pi,dot,sqrt,power
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:pi:12j, 0:2 * pi:12j]
surface_x=sin(phi)*cos(theta)
surface_y=sin(phi)*sin(theta)
surface_z=cos(phi) 

def sphere(x,y,z,r):

    return mlab.mesh(r*surface_x+x,r*surface_y+y,r*surface_z+z,color=(0.5,0.5,0.5))

def read_file(file):
    f=pd.read_csv(file,sep='\s+')

    return f


file=read_file('Input file')
mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(1, 1, 1), fgcolor=(0, 0, 0), size=(400, 300))

for i in range(6):
    sphere(file.x[i],file.y[i],file.z[i],file.r[i])

mlab.show()
```

However, I only ended up with empty figures, so is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that the values given by file's attributes are correct?

Comment: Problem solved. It was indeed an error with the input file itself.